# Google Maps v2 for Android 10 not working even when using SupportMapFragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, android-2.3-gingerbread

I imported google_play_services_lib from the Eclipse extras into my Workspace.
I created a new Android Project and included google_play_services_lib as a library.
My Project has android-support-v4.jar and google-play-services.jar

Now My Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- add for map2 -->
<permission
    android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY API NUMBER" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.phanism.gingerbreadmaps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My activity_main is:

```
package com.phanism.gingerbreadmaps;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

}
```

And my layout file is :

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.phanism.MainActivity"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

When I compile the above code, in emulator, I am being asked to update the Google Play Store. When I press OK, I am getting this error.
On a Device, I my App is crashing directly and when I look at the Debugging, this is the error I am getting.

```
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1409)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:824)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
12-3 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-03 08:43:06.851: E/AndroidRuntime(620):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone point out to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: As pointed out in one answer, you're missing to set the Google Play Services version in your manifest, but it would be great if you could post your complete logcat of the exception. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your manifest file :

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I added the above code to the manifest file, I am getting :

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value 
 '@integer/google_play_services_version').

Answer (score 0):

Hey add the following code as a child element of application tag

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY API NUMBER" />
```

Hope this will help you, if not as @Siddarth Vyas said add the google play services version too then it should work.

**EDIT**

Also change your xml code for fragment tag

it should be

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

and not

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

I hope it should solve your problem as that is the only change I see for your code from my working example code.

Comment: I did but I am getting a NullPointException.

Answer (score 0):

what about `apikey` and `service version` like this

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR API KEY" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

please put this in your **manifest.xml** file and `re run` your code what happen.

**please post error message or logcat.**

Happy coding!.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this question. The assigning the GoogleMap should be in a if-condition as mentioned below

```
if(googleMap == null){
        GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
        options.compassEnabled(true).mapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL).zoomControlsEnabled(true).rotateGesturesEnabled(true);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);
        googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();

        if(googleMap != null){
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            double latitude = 35.1;
            double longitude = 43.9;

            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("This Works");
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);

        }
    }
```

Without the if-condition, I am getting a NullPointerException.
If I dont add,

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I am getting a Fragment class error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.phanism.gingerbreadmaps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

**<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY API NUMBER" />**

</application>

</manifest>
```